# What is this lightbulb fixture, and how do I change it?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light-bulb

This is the lightbulb above my shower. I have removed an outer fixture covering already, but now I am faced with a light bulb that cannot be unscrewed easily. It is mounted to the ceiling in a plastic fixture I have not seen before.

What is the appropriate way to replace this bulb? Am I able to replace it with a regular screw-on light bulb, or do I need to purchase something different?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That appears to be a common threaded CFL light bulb. Just twist it out. Grab it down by the base so you don't break the glass tubing, and be sure to dispose of it properly and in accordance with local regulations. Fluorescent lights tend to contain mercury.

If I'm wrong and it has some sort of pin arrangement, remove the screw visible in the images, squeeze the spring straps and lower the assembly out of the can to see it better. It should be apparent how it comes out (or that it's non-serviceable, but I've never seen a fluorescent light that was).

Answer (score 2):

I've had a CFL can light like this which was GU24. One of the selling points of GU24 was more space for the electronics so the large base makes me suspect that's what you might have.

If that's what it is, it won't twist far but it can require a good amount of torque to unlock. If you can, follow isherwood's advice and grab the base to apply force. Once unlocked, it just falls out.

Comment: I've made the mistake of trying to undo a bayonet base by twisting the spiral. Lucky not to have cut myself; that one shattered politely. If it isn't moving easily, you could try pushing in gently; f it moves, try turning gently. If that doesn't do it. yeah, grab by base.